# Dynamica string count in NSMutableArray in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary, nsmutablestring

I am familiar with getting a string count from a known array

```
    int numberOfWords = [self.wordArray count];
```

but I have an unknown number of strings in an unknown number of arrays, all referenced by a dictionary.  This works - good.

```
   NSMutableDictionary *eqClasses = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

The arrays and strings are added at runtime (with help of this board):

```
            NSMutableArray* array = [eqClasses objectForKey:wordPattern];
            if(!array) {
                // create new array and add to dictionary if wordPattern not found
                array = [NSMutableArray array];
                [eqClasses setObject:array forKey:wordPattern];
            }
            [array addObject:tempWordStr];
```

Now I need to iterate through the dictionary and get the array with the largest word count. Is there a way to scroll through all the arrays in the dictionary without using a key (I won't know all the word patterns as they are generated dynamically), AND once I find the array with the most words, get that array/value and key/wordpattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a way to get all the keys within a dictionary:

```
NSArray *keyArray = [myDict allKeys];
```

And then you just go through the array and get the object for each key.
A fast enumeration should work nicely.

```
for (NSString *string in NSArray){
    ...
} //Assuming your keys are strings!
```

You can save each string to a temporary string, and when encountering a new string, compare to find the longer one. If it's longer, replace the old string with the longer one.

Hope this helped! ^_^

Comment: The allKeys does return what I need - thanks.  But am new to objective C so I am having trouble with the next part you describe. I need to use the keys to go through the dictionary described above.  You have probably explained, but a bit more snippet would be appreciated.

Comment: This is bad syntax but something like I am trying in conjunction with your example code above:                                            int numberOfWords = [eqClasses objectForKey:string count];

Comment: See if my 2nd answer makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

^_^
Okay, so now that you have an array full of all the keys in the dictionary,
you can iterate through the entire array and get the corresponding value (the string) for each key.

```
NSArray *keyArray = [myDict allKeys]; //This gets all the keys
NSString *tempString = @""; //This is the string you will save the longest string in. It gets updated when a longer string is found in the following loop.

for (NSString *string in keyArray){
    NSString *stringFromCurrentKey = [myDict objectForKey:string];
    if(stringFromCurrentKey.length > tempString.length){
        tempString = stringFromCurrentKey;
    }
} //By the end, you should be left with the longest string contained in tempString!
```

^_^ Hope this made sense and helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
NSArray *largestArray = nil;

for (NSString *key in dictionary)
{
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    if (array.count > largestArray.count) // largestArray.count is 0 if largestArray is nil
    {
        largestArray = array;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Edit:** Fixed the fact that NSDictionary returns the keys during fast enumeration.